# Правильно ли ставить точку? Как лучше стилистически?

Tags: пунктуация

Если в тексте идет предложение: "то приходим к следующему выводу", и далее идут объяснения в нескольких предложениях, причем первое начинается с "Так как", то правильно ли ставить точку после "То приходим к следующему выводу"?

То есть:
То приходим к следующему выводу. Так как... (дальше несколько предложений)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете **поставить точку,** что соответствует правилам.

В то же время вывод, состоящий  из нескольких предложений, нужно составить стилистически правильно. Возможно, начинать текст с придаточного предложения — это не лучший вариант.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87#pp87

9. Точка ставится в конце предложения, **вводящего в дальнейшее развернутое изложение:** Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ]; Представьте себе следующее, [дальше — подробное повествование]; Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание].